# cant install umbraco via nuget visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, content-management-system, umbraco

i cant install umbraco on visual studio 2017

```
    Install-Package : Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2' is not compatible with 'UmbracoCms 7.10.4 
constraint: Newtonsoft.Json (>= 10.0.2 && < 11.0.0)', 'UmbracoCms.Core 7.10.4 constraint: Newtonsoft.Json (>= 10.0.2 && < 
11.0.0)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package UmbracoCms
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageComma 
   nd
```

Comment: which version of newtonsoft would you suggest?

Comment: Update your Newtonsoft.Json version from 11.0.2 to **(>= 10.0.2 && < 11.0.0)'** this might work

Comment: Are you trying to install Umbraco on an existing solution, or is this a completely clean solution? If the former, try installing it in a clean solution, and if that works check your dependencies against what Umbraco has installed - it is likely that there's a dependency conflict somewhere.